# Issue in setting redirect URL in OneDrive application

Tags: onedrive

I have Integrated OneDrive with my web application, on my local machine 
for testing I had used http://localhost:123/Web/xyz in redirect URL on **Application Registration Portal** and it worked fine, but now I have deployed ny application on local server for further testing before going live and wanted to update Redirect URL to http://abc-xyz:81/Web/example and it gives error ***"Your URL can't contain a query string or invalid special characters."***
how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

That error message is unfortunate. The error here is likely that redirect URLs for non-localhost servers need to be HTTPS and it looks like you are using an HTTP URL.

Answer (score 0):

They have restriction about setting new redirect urls, it must be either

- match the DNS name of the existing
- sub domain of exiting

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-redirect-uris for more details